# Can I use op-amp together with PCM5102A?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac

Is it possible to use op-amp with PCM5102A? In my application the load is much lower than 10k, so as a result I have much lower Vrms than it's defined in the data-sheet (2.1V). Maybe it's possible to use op-amp together with this chip or should I use a different chip for this application then?

Comment: *Is it possible to use op-amp with PCM5102A* Use the opamp **how**, to do **what**? Try to avoid "Is it possible" questions as "is it possible" is too generic especially with opamps as they are very universal components. I could use an opamp to make a better (cleaner) supply voltage for the PCM5102 but that's probably not what you're asking.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the result I would expect from this is higher Vrms at lower loads

Answer (score 0):

It has a voltage output, you are free to do with that what you wish. An opamp or opamp and buffer should be fine. The data sheet has a recommended output load resistance which you should try to meet.